# Why does this Dafny assertion involving arrays fail?

Tags: arrays, verification, dafny

I am working on a verified implementation of gaussian elimination and I am having problems verifying this super simple method that adds the contents of the array b to the contents of the array a.  Here is the code.

```
method addAssign(a: array<real>, b: array<real>)
   requires a != null && b != null && a.Length == b.Length;
   modifies a
   ensures forall k:: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] == old(a[k]) + b[k];
{
   var i := 0;
   assert a == old(a);
   while(i < a.Length)
      invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
      invariant forall k:: i <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] == old(a[k])
      invariant forall k:: 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] == old(a[k]) + b[k];
   {
      assert a[i] == old(a[i]); // dafny verifies this
      a[i] := a[i] + b[i];
      assert a[i] == old(a[i]) + b[i]; // dafny says this is an assertion violation
      i := i + 1;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I deleted my first answer since it didn't work).

It seems that the problem is that Dafny detects potential aliasing problems. As an experiment, I first modified your code to get an even easier function which does verify:

```
method addOne(a: array<real>)
   requires a != null;
   modifies a;
   ensures forall k:: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] == old(a[k]) + 1.0;
{
   var i := 0;
   assert a == old(a);
   while(i < a.Length)
      invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
      invariant forall k:: i <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] == old(a[k])
      invariant forall k:: 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] == old(a[k]) + 1.0;
   {
      assert a[i] == old(a[i]); // dafny verifies this
      a[i] := a[i] + 1.0;
      assert a[i] == old(a[i]) + 1.0; // dafny *doesn't* say this is an assertion violation
      i := i + 1;
   }
}
```

The only difference is that I am using a literal real (1.0) rather than a real drawn from `b`. Why should *that* make a difference?

Well suppose that you invoke your method with a call which looks like

```
addAssign(a,a)
```

then in the body of the function `b` and `a` both refer to the same array. Suppose, for example, that `a[0]` is 1.0. Then in the first pass through the loop you execute `a[0] := a[0] + b[0]`.

This sets `a[0]` to 2.0. But -- it *also* sets `b[0]` to 2.0.

But in this situation `assert a[0] == old(a[0]) + b[0]` is equivalent to

`assert 2.0 == 1.0 + 2.0` -- which *should* fail.

By the way -- the following *does* verify:

```
method addAssign(a: array<real>, b: array<real>)
   requires a != null && b != null && a.Length == b.Length;
   modifies a;
   ensures forall k:: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] == old(a[k]) + old(b[k]);
{
   var i := 0;
   assert a == old(a);
   while(i < a.Length)
      invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
      invariant forall k:: i <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] == old(a[k])
      invariant forall k:: 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] == old(a[k]) + old(b[k]);
   {
      assert a[i] == old(a[i]); // dafny verifies this
      a[i] := a[i] + b[i];
      assert a[i] == old(a[i]) + old(b[i]); // and also this!
      i := i + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  I tried replacing <real> with <int> in the code but I am still getting an assertion violation in the same place.  Thank you for taking the time to answer though.

Comment: That is weird -- but note that even with ints you can't with certainty assert that `x + y` is the sum of x and y because of potential overflow. What happens if you ditch the arrays and just add a couple of variables? I'm curious enough to look into this a bit, maybe even download Dafny. If I discover anything definitive I'll repost.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, this helped alot.

Comment: @MatthewGarlock Thanks for making me aware of Dafny. Even though the notation is different, its approach strongly reminded me of the book "The Science of Programming" by David Gries which I had looked at a bit back in grad school. Doubtless that book is no longer state-of-the-art, but it is still worth reading.